# select multiple photos from library but i don't want to select same photo from the album

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uipickerview

select multiple photos from library but i don't want to  select same photo from the album
    can any one give me sample code of this,i have searched alote but i didn't get any

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL11 = %@", [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]);

    for (int k=0; k<[[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] count]; k++)
    {
        [arr_selectedPhotos addObject:[[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] objectAtIndex:k]];
    }

    NSLog(@"selectedPhotos = %@", arr_selectedPhotos);
    NSLog(@"selectedPhotos123 = %@", [arr_selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:0]);

    [tbl_SmartPost reloadData];


}
```

Comment: Use AssetLibrary, instead of `UIImagePickerController` this will give you more options to your situation. See this http://five.agency/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/ for more help.